# Legitimate question was put on hold then removed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345145/i-want-to-send-data-android-from-pc), by [HiddenParts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883715/hiddenparts), was removed shortly after I edited it. Here's a snapshot of what it looked like after my edit:

> [image]

It appeared to be a very poor question (bad grammar + opinion "could you recommend me a library"), and was put on hold. However, I realized his goal was impossible, and that no library existed. I planned on editing the question for grammar (keeping the original meaning) then answering it.

USB OTG is a means for mobile devices to act as USB hosts. A computer can only be a USB host, and you can't have host-to-host communication, so naturally there is no library for a computer to talk to an Android device using USB OTG. The answer to the question of "could you recommend me a library" is that a library didn't exist as this type of communication is not possible - which isn't opinion based, and would be useful to the community.

Why was it deleted?

Comment: Not directly answering your question of `why was it deleted`, but editing another users question to completely change what he was asking for is not appropriate.  If you think the info is that valuable, you should post your own question and answer

Comment: The revision history indicates no edits to that post by other users.  Was the post deleted before your edit went through?

Comment: I would have closed it as off-topic, recommendation, myself.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I didn't change the meaning of the question, I simply edited the grammar.

Comment: Your edit never went through, the question was deleted before it was visible to anyone but reviewers and you.

Comment: @user2461391 sorry, that wasn't apparent from the phrasing of your question and imgr is blocked at work, so I couldn't see your image (I'm assuming it contains the content of your edit?).

Comment: This does seem to be a very aggressive deletion.  @AndrewBarber can you see if it was deleted by a diamond mod or a couple of 20K users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question was flagged by two community members, closed by a community member and a mod, and deleted by another mod 5 hours later.

This is the entire text of the question in its current state:

> I want to send to the host in the client data using the Android USB
>   Host API.
>
> code to send host processes the data is present in the Net.
>
> However, code that client to send data to the host does not exist even
>   if the search.
>
> I want to send data between Android and Pc by using the OTG Cable.
>
> Recommend Please be transmitted using the Library some good?
>
> Please recommend if you have a good client code.
>
> How to reference, using the JAVA on Windows is useful to me.

It is clearly apparent that the question is not salvageable.  Normally we wait two days before deleting, but there's no compelling reason this kind of question needs to stay on the site.

Comment: Even google translate isn't that bad. What happened?!